# Improve software responsiveness when slider is manipulated in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I have a slider in my windows phone 7.1 project. When manipulated, this slider fires an event which starts a background worker to performs several trigonometric operations.

If I move the cursor on the slider, I have a certain delay in the response although I have implement background worker cancelAsync method in manipulationstarted event,  I would like more responsiveness, how can I achieve this?

Code:

```
   private void sliderCosinus_ManipulationStarted(object sender,ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            bw.CancelAsync();   // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
        }
    }

     private void sldCosinus_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Value = Convert.ToInt32(sldCosinus.Value) * 10;
        }
        catch
        {
             // errore message here
        }
        finally 
        {
        }
    }
     private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;


            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => app.IsEffectApplied=TrigonometricTrans()
    // TrigonomtriecTrans calculate sin and cosinus for every pixel in image 
            }
    }
    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // progress bar here 
    }
    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Cancelled == true))
        {
            //this.tbProgress.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (!(e.Error == null))
        {
            //this.tbProgress.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
           DoubleBufferToScreen();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like your code may not be fully optimized - please post your code so we can see :)